# I'm messing up my inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, sfml

So I've got a Piece class supposed to represent pieces on a board, from which I plan to have two other classes inheriting.  I've gotten a lot of problems in doing so, however; here is the relevant code so far.

```
///
/// PIECE CLASS HERE
/// this is an abstract class from which Barrier and Pawn inherit.

class Piece
{
public:
    Piece(Space* start);
    sf::Shape m_Circle;
protected:
    int m_X;
    int m_Y;
    int m_radius;
    Space* CurrentSpace;
};

Piece::Piece(Space* start):
    m_X(start->GetX()),
    m_Y(start->GetY()),
    m_radius(14),
    CurrentSpace(start)
{}

///
/// BARRIER CLASS HERE
/// these are the white stones that block a player's path

class Barrier : public Piece
{
public:
    Barrier(Space* initial);
    void Move(Space* target, bool isCapturing);
};

Barrier::Barrier(Space* initial)
{
    Piece(initial);
    m_Circle = sf::Shape::Circle((float)m_X, (float)m_Y, (float)m_radius, sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
    Move(initial);
}

void Barrier::Move(Space* target, bool isCapturing)
{
    int xChange = abs(target->GetX() - m_X);
    int yChange = abs(target->GetY() - m_Y);
    m_Circle.Move((float)xChange, (float)yChange);
    CurrentSpace.ToggleOccupied();
    if(!isCapturing)
    {
        (*target).ToggleOccupied();
    }
    CurrentSpace = target;
}
```

I'm getting loads of errors I don't understand, in particular:

```
no matching function for call to Piece::Piece()
declaration of 'Piece initial' shadows a parameter
no matching function for call to 'Barrier::Move(Piece&)'
request for member 'ToggleOccupied' in '((Barrier*)this)->Barrier::<anonymous>.Piece::CurrentSpace', which is of non-class type 'Space*'|
```

Being new to C++, I don't understand what's going wrong with any of this.  I tried to build my code analogous to the code I found in the book I used to learn C++, but apparently I've overlooked some subtlety.  All the functions that I try to call seem to exist in the appropriate places, and I define them with the same values as in their prototype, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first error is caused by this:

```
Barrier::Barrier(Space* initial)
{
    Piece(initial);
    m_Circle = sf::Shape::Circle((float)m_X, (float)m_Y, (float)m_radius, sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
    Move(initial);
}
```

Needs to look like:

```
Barrier::Barrier(Space* initial) : Piece(initial)
{
    m_Circle = sf::Shape::Circle((float)m_X, (float)m_Y, (float)m_radius, sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
    Move(initial);
}
```

The base class' constructor runs before your constructor (no matter what) -- you need to pass arguments to it if it requires arguments in the initialization list.

I'm not sure about the other errors because I don't know which lines they're occurring on.

Comment: The second error is a result of the same: `Piece(initial)` inside the class braces declares a local variable, then `Move(initial)` is trying to pass a `Piece` lvalue to the `Barrier::Move` function.

Answer (score 4):

The parenthesis in the line

```
Piece(initial);
```

are ignored by the compiler. You are declaring a variable with the same name as the parameter:

```
Piece initial;
```

To initialize the `Piece` base object with `initial`, you have to use the member initializer list:

```
Barrier::Barrier(Space* initial) : Piece(initial)
```

Also, the `Move` function expects two arguments, but you're only passing one. You forgot the boolean.

Comment: No, I think he's just calling functions and passing the parameter `initial`.

Comment: @Billy: `Piece` is not a function, but `Move` is.

Comment: Yeah, that line creates a temporary Piece object on the stack, initializes it with initial, then discards it immediately.  There's no declaration going on...

Comment: `Piece(initial);` is declaring a variable, `Move(initial);` is calling a function.

Comment: @Adrian: You're wrong. Try `int main(int argc, char** argv) { std::string(argv); }`, for example. If you were correct, the compiler would complain about a missing constructor (there is no `string` constructor taking a `char**`). Instead, it warns about the shadowing of a parameter, because `std::string(argv);` is declaring a `string` variable named `argv`. This follows the basic rule of C++ that says "If it looks like a declaration, it is a declaration".

Comment: @Xeo: You *can* disambiguate with parenthesis: `(std::string(argv));` will create and immediately destroy a string object. Or rather, it would, if there were an appropriate constructor.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Ah -- the function I was referring to was `Piece::Piece()`. I see your point though. +1

Comment: @Billy: `Piece::Piece()` is not a normal member function, it's a constructor. Since `Piece` is a typename, `Piece(initial);` is a variable declaration. not a function call. (If `Piece` was no typename, then `Piece(initial);` indeed would be a function call, provided there was such a function.)

Comment: @FredOverflow: I know, I know -- I was thinking of it like I spec'd in my answer. You are correct of course.

Comment: @Billy: Sorry for being pedantic. I can't help it, I'm a C++ programmer ;)

Comment: @Fred: Lol -- no, I understand completely. :) I'm usually pedantic myself. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize the super class, you should do it like this:

```
Barrier(Space* initial): 
    Piece(initial) {
    ...
}
```

If you don't explicitly initialize the base type, the compiler will try to initialize it by calling a constructor with an empty argument list, like this:

```
Barrier(Space* initial):
    Piece() {
    ... 
}
```

But since you don't define a constructor for Piece that takes zero arguments, you get the compiler error you described.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers, all. Plus that final daunting line

`request for member 'ToggleOccupied' in '((Barrier*)this)->Barrier::<anonymous>.Piece::CurrentSpace', which is of non-class type 'Space*'|`

is being caused from

`CurrentSpace.ToggleOccupied();`

you have declared CurrentSpace to be a pointer, so this should be

CurrentSpace->ToggleOccupied();

Comment: Wow, you guys are awesome.  Hopefully my coding skills will eventually be up to the level that I can help others!  I fixed it, and it all works again.  Thanks a million!